# How to end interface callback after activity end

Tags: java, android

I have question regarding functionality of interfaces. 
Both my class are using AndroidViewModel which supplies Application as parameter for constructor.

My question when activity A starts activty B, why is class A onUpdate still invoked as finish() method has been invoked. Please help me understand this part.

It causes my app to crash with following error

```
Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@236c862 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

**A.java**

```
    class A extends AppCompatActivity implements C.listenerX{
        Context context;
        LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            context = this;
            loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(
            ....
            startActivty(new Intent(this, B.class));
            finish();

        }
    }

    class B extends AppCompatActivity implements C.listenerX{
        Context context;
        LoginViewModel loginViewModel;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            context = this;
            loginViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(LoginViewModel.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpdate(
            ....
            startActivty(new Intent(this, 

        }
    }

    class C {
        public interfaces listenerX{
            void onUpdate();
        }
    ...
    }
```

Comment: How do you setup your listener in the `ViewModel`? Is your listener lifecycle-aware in any way?

Comment: share your LoginViewModel class

Answer (score 0):

Why are you keeping a reference in Activity pointing to the activity?

```
 Context context;
 context = this;
```

Why are you using ViewModel in such a way? It will outlive your Activity. You have to be lifecycle aware as Pawel said. So just delete these interfaces.

ViewModel is part of the MVVM pattern. In the pattern the ViewModel has no idea of any views. It exposes stream of that the Views are observing. You need to have in the ViewModel:

```
private val _onUpdate = MutableLiveData<Event<Boolean>()
    val onUpdate : LiveData<Boolean>
        get() = _onUpdate
```

And then you can observe it in the View like this:

```
viewModel.onUpdate.observe(this, EventObserver {// Do what you need})
```

You can refer to this article how Events are working with LiveData:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150

On your question how the Events work. Let's be clear first how LiveData works. You set same data in it, for example a String.

```
//In the model
LiveData name = new MutableLiveData<String>

//In the view

// Create the observer which updates the UI.
        final Observer<String> nameObserver = new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable final String newName) {
                // Update the UI, in this case, a TextView.
                nameTextView.setText(newName);
            }
        };
```

Now once you set the name no every device rotation the name will be there and the TextView will be updated. In the moment you start observing you not only observe future data, but also receive the last one.

So in another case. You try to access a server. But the server replies that the user is not authenticated. You want to ask the user to authenticate. You can do it with LiveData. Observe it and on trigger you show the dialog. The problem here is that if the user rotates the screen you will observer the same data again and show dialog again. You don't want to do that so you need an Event. How it works: You have flag "hasBeenHandled" and if some observer receives the data once, the flag is set to true and any subsequent observers will receive null. There is also a method: peekContent so you can force reading the data. And the EventObserver is a class to handle the boilerplate code.

If you are using LiveData it will know when the Activity is in the right State and it will never be notified when it is dead.

Also are you aware that both the activities are referring to different instances of the ViewModel? If you want to share something you need to have Fragments in the same Activity.

You should hardly ever use AndroidViewModel!!!

Comment: I just read the article. Its written in kotlin. Do you mind explaining in java way how SingleLiveEvent works. I think i am begining to understand how live data, view model works. But no where to find article on SingleLiveEvent

Comment: @KIRPALSINGH Just check the articles from Jose Alcerreca. He is one of the lead devs about this stuff. Check these apps: https://github.com/android/architecture-samples . And you should start using Kotlin.